# Shortest paths network

Tags: r, networking, shortest-path

I have a problem in computing the shortest paths in a network in R. In particular, I have randomized a two-mode network with the following code:

```
library(tnet)
n1 <- 441
n2 <- 210
ptie <- nrow(data_network)/(n1*n2)
random_data <- rg_tm(ni=n1, np=n2,ties=ptie, seed = 1000)
random_network = network(random_data,matrix.type="edgelist",directed = TRUE)
```

But then when I try to compute the shortest paths with the following code:

```
distance_tm(random_network, projection.method="sum")
```

I have the following error:

```
Error in if (ncol(net) == 3) { : the argument has lenght zero
```

Does anyone knows why? The same happens with the following real two mode network:

```
structure(list(owner = c("ABBA JEANS MINING Sprl", "ABBA JEANS MINING Sprl", "ACACIA Sprl", "ACACIA Sprl", "ACACIA Sprl", "ACACIA Sprl", "AFRICAN ENGINEERING CORPORATE Sprl",  "AFRICAN ENGINEERING CORPORATE Sprl", "AFRICAN ENGINEERING CORPORATE Sprl",  "AFRICAN MINERALS (Barbados) Ltd Sprl"), armed_band = c("Mayi Mayi Militia (Bakata Katanga)",  "Militia (Elements)", "Batwa Ethnic Militia", "FDD", "Militia (Kamwina Nsapu)",  "RCD-Goma", "Anti-Balaka", "Kuluna Communal Militia", "Militia (Kamwina Nsapu)",  "Mayi Mayi Militia (Bakata Katanga)"), freq = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 4,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```